# Why does my python/pygame application not pop up properly

Tags: python, macos, pygame, .app

I have made a program with python and pygame and bundled it into a .app file using py2app. It just doesn't open up properly when i click the icon, it doesn't appear on the screen until i click the icon on the dock, by then some of the code has already ran and it ruins the point of the actual program.

I also can't seem to change the icon from the normal icon to the icon that i made, i have put it into the folder, replacing the default one. The icon doesn't appear on the dock, the pygame snake does.

Finally will the .app file work on any mac?

BTW, this is just a program for some fun
Code:

```
import random, pygame, time, sys

time.sleep(2)
colour_1 = (0,255,255)
colour_2 = (0,255,0)
colour_3 = (255,255,0)
colour_4 = (255,0,0)
colour_5 = (0,0,255)


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
h = 500
w = 500

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

pygame.display.set_caption("You just lost the game")
alpha = 255

shape = screen.convert_alpha()

stimulus = pygame.Rect(0,0,500,500)
def the_game():
    #Makes the text "the game" and the text "you just lost it" fade into the screen
    global alpha
    alpha = alpha - 5
    ##############
    Font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",40,True,False)
    Text = Font.render("The Game",1,white)
    screen.blit(Text,(140,125))
    pygame.draw.rect(shape,(0,0,0,alpha),stimulus)
    screen.blit(shape,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update(stimulus)
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)



def lost_it():
    #Writes "the game" and "you just lost it" onto the screen
    Font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",40,True,False)
    Text = Font.render("The Game",1,(white))
    text = Font.render("YOU JUST LOST IT",1,(white))
    screen.blit(text,(50,250))
    screen.blit(Text,(140,125))
    pygame.display.update()


def flash():
    #Writes "the game" and "you just lost it" onto the screen
    #Changes the background colour of the screen
    Font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",40,True,False)
    Text = Font.render("The Game",1,(black))
    text = Font.render("YOU JUST LOST IT",1,(black))
    rand = random.randint(0,5)
    if rand == 1:
        screen.fill(colour_1)
    if rand == 2:
        screen.fill(colour_2)
    if rand == 3:
        screen.fill(colour_3)
    if rand == 4:
        screen.fill(colour_4)
    if rand == 5:
        screen.fill(colour_5)
    screen.blit(text,(50,250))
    screen.blit(Text,(140,125))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit(); sys.exit();




while True:
    if alpha == 0:
        break
    else:
        the_game()


time.sleep(1)
lost_it()
while True:
    flash()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

Comment: You need to show some minimal code that we can run to see what you are doing to have any chance of getting an answer to this question.   I'm loving the idea of you licking the icon to make it appear though - full marks for that :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in pygame.display called set_icon. You can use it to override default snake icon